# 500 internal server error - Hosting nopCommerce 4.0 on Godaddy with Windows Plesk (not VPS) Account

Tags: e-commerce, hosting, plesk, nopcommerce

I know how to install and setup nopCommerce.

However this is specific to hosting it on Godaddy Windows Plesk account, I have searched, looked and read many threads, documents on nopCommerce 4.0 and hosting it or installing it. However I am unable to successfully install nopCommerce 4.0 on Godaddy Windows Plesk (not VPS) Hosting.

I get 500 internal server error, looks like .NET Core is not supported on Windows Plesk hosting on Godaddy, on VPS hosting it works.

So is any one able to successfully do it on Plesk?

Comment: You will need .net framework 4.61+ and .net core 2.0+ runtime to successfully run nopCommerce 4.0.

Comment: Thanks. I just had a chat with Godaddy customer service. And it is clear that Plesk does not support .NET Core. They suggested to go with private server hosting. Looks like this it then.

Comment: In case, any one wants to know, software versions of their account on GoDaddy, take a look at https://in.godaddy.com/help/software-versions-on-hosting-accounts-897 It was shared by their customer support

Comment: No, you dont need VPS. nopCommerce can run fine on shared hosting. If your hosting provider support Full Trust and requirement above, then it will work. FYI, I also run nopCommerce site on asphostportal and I use their shared hosting

Comment: @MarkSpencer, CAS is set to full. No one said, it does not work on shared hosting. This discussion, is specific to GD Plesk hosting, where, it does not yet have .NET Core 2.0. Once they do it will, till then it won't.

Comment: @jd_ Trust me, it is working on shared hosting. Although Plesk doesnt support ASP.NET Core, but if your hosting provider has installed it on the server, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above:

You will need .net framework 4.61+ and .net core 2.0+ runtime to successfully run nopCommerce 4.0.

And as mentioned by you

GoDaddy with Plesk does not support .NET Core yet.
See https://in.godaddy.com/help/software-versions-on-hosting-accounts-897

Answer (score 0):

In .net core, iis is not really used as a web service, its just use to point users to application. Application is a exe file so actually windows will run it, so i dont think that its a issue of plex or something like that.
I hade same error for nop4 on vps, but i cant tell you any advice if you don't check logs.
Try see the logs,application set logs automatically as a text file. 
You may solve when check that file or create another question so we can help you and others who had the same error

Comment: I know. I will do some more digging into it on plex and post additional information. My last resort is to fall back to 3.9 and close this question.

Comment: Listen, 3.9 is most stablest version of nopcommerce as i think .net core changes are not completely done in nop4 so i use nop3.9 till nop4.1 release,
But check logs before changing version for once

Comment: I have a feeling that, the way godaddy's plex accounts are set up (even though it is windows hosting). It does not allow exe file to run which is what is happening with .net core nop 4.0. Thanks for your reply.